# How to ignore key in nested JSON (because it has variable name)

Tags: python, json, nested-json

I have following JSON, where element "Key_with_variable_name" has variable name compared to other keys:

```
{
    "Key1": {
        "Key11": {
            "Key111": "Value111",
            "Key112": "Value112",
            "Key113": "Value113",
            "Key114": {
                "Key1141": {
                    "Key_with_variable_name": {
                        "Key114111": {
                            "Key1141111": "Value1141111",
                            "Key1141112": "Value1141112",
                            "Key1141113": "Value1141113"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I access `Key114111` (get its name) which is "under" `Key_with_variable_name` and then access nested `Key1141111` and it's value `Value1141111`? And can I get value of Key_with_variable_name?

I used `json_message = json.loads(jsonObject)` and worked on JSON as nested dictionary, but struggled to get down deep past `"Key_with_variable_name"`

Or maybe it can be done easier working on JSON not on dictionary?

Comment: you need to create a recursive function to do that

Comment: @deadshot but I don't know the name of "Key_with_variable_name" - it can be different for the same JSON schema.

Comment: Are you aware of the dictionary methods `keys()`, `values()` and `items()`?